# i2cdetect shows addresses starting from 8

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have currently installed the latest raspbian as of posting this question.

I have an i2c device with address 0x03 which works when running my program I successfully communicate with it, but when I run `i2cdetect` I only see devices starting from address 0x08.

```
$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `i2cdetect -a -y 1`

default range is from 0x08 to 0x77

NOTE `man i2cdetect` will show this (and other options)

Comment: But it used to start at 3 just before I had to reinstall. My old card was some 3 years old so I'm guessing that's an update..

Comment: AFAIK this has been so for years. Some versions use default: from 0x03 to 0x77  but this is Debian Bullseye version

Comment: My old card had raspbian based on buster, and it showed 0x03-0x077, just for reference. What is the reason for the first few addresses to be hidden?